# Number of iems in an array containing a part of string

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, filter

consider

```
df['something'].unique()
```

This generates unique items in variable something. Lets consider it as array of unique items.

```
array(['aabb','aacc','aadd','bbcc']).
```

Now I want to check how any items in that array starts from 'aa'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas solution with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with `sum` for count `True`s:

```
print (pd.Series(df['something'].unique()).str.startswith('aa').sum())
3
```

Alternative is [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) - then `Series` constructor is not necessary:

```
print (df['something'].drop_duplicates().str.startswith('aa').sum())
3
```

Or pure python solution - generator with `sum` and `startswith` for count `True`s:

```
print (sum(x.startswith('aa') for x in df['something'].unique()))
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module to find any patterns (not just 'aa')

For example:
if you have the following array `arr = ['aabb','aacc','aadd','bbcc']`, you can find the number of elements that start with 'aa' with this line of code:

```
len([word for word in arr if re.match(r'aa', word)])
```

This will give you the output of `3`, while this line

```
len([word for word in arr if re.match(r'bb', word)])
```

will show `1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `startswith()`. Therefore, the code would be:

```
number_of_aa = len([x for x in df['something'].unique() if x.startswith('aa')])
```

With this method you get a filtered list with the values that start with `aa` and then by using `len` you get the count. If you do not wish to retain the values, you can simply use True/False and then sum the values:

```
number_of_aa = [True for x in df['something'].unique() if x.startswith('aa')].sum()
```

Comment: second is `sum([True for x in df['something'].unique() if x.startswith('aa')])`

Comment: or convert to np.array, but now not working `[True for x in df['something'].unique() if x.startswith('aa')].sum()`